# tracert - routing loop?

Tags: traceroute

I was trying to access Paypal dev blog but got a connection timed out error instead. Other sites are working fine. So I did a trace route if I would see something flaky. Indeed something came up.

[image: Screenshot here.]

Comment: Where are you based?  The private IP is unusual but not unheard of.  The last ip that registered is in Malaysia, so perhap there is a problem with routing somewhere around there.

Comment: I am in Malaysia too. Is it a routing loop that I am seeing here?

Comment: Sorry, didn't look at it properly.  There is definitely a loop and your own next hop is participating repeatedly, which is very weird.  I'd raise it with your ISP.

Comment: @Paul: Sorry to "steal" the info you already provided...  I decided that based on Superuser's structure, such info belonged in an answer.  Plus I noticed some other details, so I placed it all in an answer.

Comment: @TOOGAM No problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  This trace is not normal.

There are multiple issues, encountered when tracert tried to reach devblog.paypal.com (173.0.94.54).  They include:

- After communicating with 219.93.218.177, the next response comes from 10.64.4.205.  IPv4 addresses starting with "10.", "172.16." through "172.31.", or "192.168." are considered "private IP addresses", and most other (non-special) addresses are typically described as "public".  Since 219.93.218.177 and PayPal's 173.0.94.50
- an IPv4 address is repeated.  Notably, the second hop (which is the first one after your private address) is 219.93.218.177 and that also appears as the 6th hop (4 hops later), and the 8th and 10th and 13th hops
- The response times go from 43ms (normal-ish) to 999ms, 1948ms, 3054ms.  That is undesirable.  I wouldn't freak out too much about this occurring once, if the situation resolved itself and everything else worked fine.  However, it seems to be likely to be an item of concern.

219.93.218.177 is registered to TMNET (ADSL-STREAMYX-TMNET), per [APNIC WHOIS](https://wq.apnic.net/apnic-bin/whois.pl).  The report of that IP address also noted some E-Mail address contacts.  Some of those E-Mail addresses, like one for reporting abuse, is rather common to find.  I also noticed this one:

> remarks:        ipmc_ipcore@tm.com.my [for routing related]

I suggest that you send that E-Mail address a copy of your Traceroute log (and details on how they can get back to you).  If the issue is urgent, you may also wish to call a phone number listed on those results:

> phone:          +6-1800-88-2646
>   phone:          +603-83185434

or contact them through some other method, possibly by using information from [TMNet's "Contact Us" page](https://www.tm.com.my/OnlineHelp/ContactUs/Pages/default.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation. It is indeed what I am looking for. It happened few days ago and I did what you'd suggested. I did a trace again just now and it appears to be routing normally. Cheers <3

Comment: The fact is, I still have some doubt. I've opened another question thread here - https://superuser.com/questions/1068530/is-this-trace-normal-part-2