# tracert - no ICMP replies after second hop

Tags: traceroute

This is a follow up question to my previous one [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1068372/is-this-trace-normal).

I did a trace again but to a different host. Is this trace normal?

[image: trace]

What I am expecting is I should be getting at least another ICMP reply from 58.26.8.93 in between hop 3 and 30. That obviously didn't happen. Perhaps could someone explain?

Comment: Perhaps you could better title the two so it's obvious what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

175.137.110.30 responded to the packet.

After that, no other devices responded to the packet.

Most frequently, nearly all routers commonly used on the Internet will respond.  This is especially true of routers towards the middle; routers close to the start or destination seem to be more prone to be unresponsive to a tracert (showing up as an asterisk *).

When the tracert ends with a system that has all asterisks, and then there are no further asterisks, the most likely scenario is that the last reported system (175.137.110.30 in this case) lost the packet, instead of routing it where it should go.  Another possibility is that 175.137.110.30 sent the packet to another device which simply doesn't report its status (which is kind of uncommon, but not necessarily a problem) and then that device lost the packet.  Either way, what appears to have happened is that eventually the packet did not ever reach any system that responded.

Since the packet left your private network (starting with "192.168.") to a public network, the problem is likely with the destination or some Internet infrastructure organization in the middle.  Since your destination is www.google.com and they have a good track record, I can narrow that down slightly by concluding that the problem is likely with some Internet infrastructure organization in the middle.  So, the fix will likely involve changing something that you do not have access to fix (like how a device is configured, or where a cable is plugged in).

The most useful action you can take is to make sure this gets reported.  Find out who the last address (175.137.110.30) belongs to, and try to get this situation reported to the organization that has 175.137.110.30 registered.

If you don't have time to work on this issue, sometimes that may be a service provided by your ISP, so you can let your ISP know and they may keep track of the progress of getting this fixed.  After all, you are a customer who, in theory, pays your ISP money to get your packets where they need to go.  When common Internet infrastructure is broken, many ISPs will make some efforts to cooperate with getting that fixed.

In this case, it looks like your ISP won't need to contact any other organization (except maybe one upstream provider, whom they are directly connected to, so they already likely have a relatively close business relationship with that organization).  So contacting your ISP is definitely worthwhile.

The last example you asked about (in the question you hyperlinked) was PayPal, a well-known organization that requires successful Internet communications to continue to live.  They are usually known to have respectable Internet connectivity.  This example is Google, an even more-well-known organization that also thrives on the Internet.  Your IPv4 addresses in the middle are different.  So this information stands some good chance of being useful, so I would contact your ISP again and provide this information as well.  Make sure to let them know that you already contacted recently with the traceroute info from PayPal.

When you report this stuff, please don't send them a screenshot.  They would typically prefer a copy-and-paste of the text.  It looks to me like you're using Microsoft Windows (based on familiarity with the font.)  So click the icon in the upper-left corner of the window once, and choose Edit, Mark.  Select the text, then click the icon and choose Edit, Copy.  Then paste.

APNIC shows 175.137.110.30 is registered to ADSL-STREAMYX IRT-TMNST-MY TELEKOM MALAYSIA BERHAD so, although some details from APNIC are a bit different for this IPv4 address (it doesn't show the "routing" E-Mail address), it does appear that the same company (your Internet provider) is using this IPv4 address as well.  I suggest using the contact info from the other question (which you hyperlinked).

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your answers. You have been a great help.